# Плавное появление подсказки

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Пишу всплывающие подсказки на сайте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: они не плавно появляются. В этом коде я пытался изначально задавать `opacity: 0`, а затем, после добавления элемента в разметку, задавать `opacity: 1`, но безуспешно. Затухают они плавно.

```js
class ModalWindow {
    constructor(title, descr) {
        this.title = title;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    alert() {
        const newAlert = document.createElement('div'),
            title = document.createElement('h3'),
            body = document.createElement('div');

        newAlert.classList.add('alert');
        body.classList.add('descr');

        title.textContent = this.title || 'Новый alert';
        body.textContent = this.descr || '';

        newAlert.appendChild(title);
        if (body.textContent !== '') {
            newAlert.appendChild(body);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(newAlert);

        newAlert.style.opacity = 1;

        setTimeout(() => {
            newAlert.style.opacity = 0;
        }, 3000);
    }
}

let newAlert = new ModalWindow();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', newAlert.alert);
```

```css
.alert {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button>кнопка</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

```js
class ModalWindow {
    constructor(title, descr) {
        this.title = title;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    alert() {
        const newAlert = document.createElement('div'),
            title = document.createElement('h3'),
            body = document.createElement('div');

        newAlert.classList.add('alert');
        body.classList.add('descr');

        title.textContent = this.title || 'Новый alert';
        body.textContent = this.descr || '';

        newAlert.appendChild(title);
        if (body.textContent !== '') {
            newAlert.appendChild(body);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(newAlert);
        
        // Here
        setTimeout(() => {
          newAlert.style.opacity = 1;
        }, 0)

        setTimeout(() => {
            newAlert.style.opacity = 0;
        }, 3000);
    }
}

let newAlert = new ModalWindow();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', newAlert.alert);
```

```css
.alert {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ToDo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button>кнопка</button>
</body>

</html>
```